# how to toggle text when checkbox(es) are checked and hide when nothing is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

When checking a checkbox, the text `Checked` is shown. When unchecking all the checkboxes, how can I hide the text `Checked`?

```js
$('.rafcheckbox').click(function() {
  $(".rafoptions").show();
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="3" />
<div class="rafoptions" style="display:none">Checked</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work you can use the `:checked` selector and the `length` property to determine if *any* of the boxes are checked. Then you can use `toggle()` to hide/show the `div` as required.

```js
var $checkboxes = $('.rafcheckbox').change(function() {
  var anyChecked = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length != 0;
  $(".rafoptions").toggle(anyChecked);
});
```

```css
.rafoptions { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="3" />
<div class="rafoptions">Checked</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `every()`, introduced in ES6

```
$(".rafcheckbox").click(function() {
    let checkedInputs = [];
    $(".rafcheckbox").each(function() {
    checkedInputs.push(this.checked)});
    if(checkedInputs.every(element => !element))
        $(".rafoptions").hide();
    else
        $(".rafoptions").show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6qkd018/3/)